# Probability measure on naturals

Tags: measure-theory

Does there exist a probability measure $μ$ on a sigma algebra of subsets of $\mathbb N = \{ 1,2,3,...\}$ such that, $$μ(\{ n\in\mathbb N :n\equiv j \bmod{N}\})=\frac{1}{N}$$ for every $j,N\in \mathbb N$?

By intuition i think that it can't be found such  measure but i don't see a contradiction..Any hint will be very helpful.

Comment: But, the question asks for a measure on "a sigma algebra" of subsets of the natural numbers and not necessary at the whole powerset

Comment: If so then clarify what you mean given my answer. How do the $a\Bbb{Z}+b \cap \Bbb{Z}_{\ge 1}$ generate a $\sigma$-algebra ?

Comment: Oh, i got it know(the part for the sigma algebra)..unfortunately i'm not so sure that i understand the argument on your comment..But it's ok if you can't explain further. I will struggle with it for a while and i hope i will get it. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

$$\mu(\{n\})\le \lim_{k\to \infty} \mu( \{ an, \gcd(a,k!)=1\})= \lim_{k\to \infty} \frac1n\frac{\phi(k!)}{k!}=\lim_{k\to \infty} \frac1n\prod_{p\le k}(1-p^{-1})=0$$

The countably infinite additivity implies that $$\mu(\Bbb{Z}_{\ge 1})= \sum_{n\ge 1}\mu(\{n\})=0$$